# After starting an Intent to an external app and return to my app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

Currently I have a `Button` which will share an URL with a friend by using WhatsApp.

However, is there a way to return them back to my app after the message has been sent?

Here is my code so far.

```
whatsapp_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent whatsapp_intent = new Intent();
        whatsapp_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        whatsapp_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey, i think you will like this. Check it out " + url);
        whatsapp_intent.setType("text/plain");
        whatsapp_intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(whatsapp_intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `return them` ? and did you try `startActivityForResult()` ?

Comment: no. you cant. after you send intent to other app, then is up to them. you cannot change other app code

Comment: I think startActivityForResult() will not work. I´ve seen it by sending Audio, Video or Images vial What´s app from other apps, it doesn´t return to this app automatically...

Comment: return as in going back to my app. I just tried using this feature in pinterest and it stays in whatsapp. Maybe its not possible

Comment: There is no way to return back automatically but you can start particular activity after certain time

Comment: @Apurva do you mean after so many seconds of starting the intent?

Comment: Invoke a thread when you send an intent to start whatsapp and set some time to make a thread wait before invoking.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give it a go but will probably leave it out of the app. Ill see how it performs